# Tesseract PDF sandwich C++

Tags: pdf

somebody know some tutorials/books/examples how to create searcheable pdf sandwich in C++ with tesseract and imagemagiK?

I have this method:

```
public void Tiff2Pdf()
{
    using (var api = OcrApi.Create())
    {
        api.Init(Languages.English);
        //Create the renderer to PDF file output. The extension will be added automatically
        using (var renderer = OcrPdfRenderer.Create("multipage_pdf_file", "c:\\YourApp\\tessdata\\"))
        {
            renderer.BeginDocument("Title");
            api.ProcessPages(@"c:\multipage.tif", null, 0, renderer);
            renderer.EndDocument();
        }
    }
}
```

Regards